# creating new dataframe with Max Value of one column using a subset of a separate column as condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, subset, multiple-columns

New to coding and this is my first challenge with a large data set:

I have a dataframe with various runways from multiple airports. I want to find out which runway is the longest for each airport. The issue is that all of the airports are in the same column.

Here's an example of what the data looks like:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfVxE.png)

I'm hoping to reduce the length of the dataframe by (or create a new, shorter dataframe with) only keeping rows belonging to the max "length_ft" for each "airport_ident".

Please help. Thanks.